# Print the contents of files from the output of a program

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a program `foo` that finds files with a certain specification and that the output of running `foo` is:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

I want to print the contents of each of those files (preferably with the file name prepended). How would I do this? I would've thought piping it to cat like so:

```
foo | cat
```

would work but it doesn't.

EDIT:

My solution to this problem prints out each file and prepends the filename to each line of output is:

```
foo | xargs grep .
```

This gets output similar to:

```
file1.txt: Hello world
file2.txt: My name is foobar.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<your command> | xargs cat
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `xargs` here:

```
foo | xargs cat
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow for file names that have spaces in them, you'll need something like this:

```
#/bin/bash
while read -r file
do
   # Check for existence of the file before using cat on it.
   if [[ -f $file ]]; then
      cat "$file"

   # Don't bother with empty lines
   elif [[ -n $file ]]; then
      echo "There is no file named '$file'"
   fi
done
```

Put this a script. Let's call it `myscript.sh`. Then, execute:

```
foo | myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo | xargs grep '^' /dev/null
```

- why grep on `^` ? to display also empty lines (replace with "." if you want only non-empty lines)
- why is there a `/dev/null` ? so that, in addition to any filename provided in "foo" output, there is at least 1 additionnal file (and a file NOT maching anything, such as /dev/null). That way there is AT LEAST 2 filenames given to grep, and thus grep will always show the matching filename.